# Python: Multiprocessing - Suds - _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class> attribute lookup failed

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, suds

I'm making SOAP WSDL connection and then I want to run function in another procces (threading is not suitable)

```
from suds.client import Client

class dTest:

def setup(self, client):
    ws = Client("http://localhost?wsdl")

    # then I use some SOAP API methods and return dictionary with results
    return result_dict


def test(self, name):
    # in this function I use another SOAP API methods
    return

def main(self, client):

    result_dict = self.setup(client)

    for  name, num in result_dict.items():
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.test, args=[name])
        p.start() # <- on this line I have an error
        p.join(timeout)
        if p.is_alive():
            p.terminate
```

Then I have an error

```
File "D:\IPWStest\test\dTest.py", line 318, in main
    p.start()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 66, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 59, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'suds.sudsobject.UserCredentialsType'>: attribute lookup UserCredentialsType on suds.sudsobject failed
```

I can't find any solution for this issue. How can I pickle this line?

> result_dict = self.setup(client)

Is another decision may be exist?
Can anyone help me? 
What does this error means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in `setup` function. Web-service connection `ws` in setup uses in `test` function. That's why this object cann't be pickle. 
If you using `multiprocessing` and `suds` or any similar lib, new connection should be created in every new process.

Comment: I am using python 3.5 and even with separate clients I get the error